# How do I create a Kubernetes Custom Resource using javascript client

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-custom-resources

My custom definition

```
apiVersion: something.com/v1alpha1
 kind: MyKind
 metadata:
   name: test
 spec:
   size: 1
   image: myimage
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297139/createdeployment-with-kubernetes-javascript-client) is an answer that shows how to create a deployment using a javascript client. However, I need to create a custom resource using a javascript client

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const k8s = require('@kubernetes/client-node')
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();
const k8sClient = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CustomObjectsApi);

var body = {
    "apiVersion": "something.com/v1alpha1",
    "kind": "MyKind",
    "metadata": {
        "name": "mycustomobject",
    },
    "spec": {
        "size": "1",
        "image": "myimage"
    }
}

k8sClient.createNamespacedCustomObject('something.com','v1alpha1','default','mykinds', body)
    .then((res)=>{
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I wasn't sure what to provide as group, version and plurals parameters.

Answer (score 2):

All the client libraries are auto-generated from the same underlying IDL so it works like in Go, [`createNamespacedCustomObject`](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/javascript/blob/ad6e451ce01f698ab18ceb03fb712e014bc93a5b/src/gen/api/customObjectsApi.ts#L209). You can also use the raw API directly too.